# Which AuthenticationType is used - Owin authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin

In our application we authenticate a user in two different ways and it works just as it should. Now I would like to know **which** AuthenticationType is used when a user tries to access a page trough a controller action and the user has signed in. Is that possible?

```
// Startup.auth.cs
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
            {
        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(...

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(...


   // Controller
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Activation()
        {
                if (!this.Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    // sign in using WsFederation, works
                }
                else if (/*Signed in with OpenIdConnect AuthType*/)
                {
                    return Redirect("/");
                }

                return View();
            }
```

What is important here is the els-if statement. I can access the OwinContext. Is there a way to know which AuthenticationType is used though it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that with this code

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Activation()
{
    if (!this.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        // sign in using WsFederation, works
    }
    else if (User.Identity.AuthenticationType == "{YOUR_AUTHENTICATION_TYPE}")
    {
        return Redirect("/");
    }

    return View();
}
```